# Insert key-Value pair to all entries of object by condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function with params and I am doing a forEach loop to add all the values from the loop.

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
            ['name']: k,
            ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
            ['type']: sd
        }));
```

I also need to add another value but it is conditional.

I am then doing to make one giant set

`let arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];`

```
let x = [];
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...x, ...data(y)];
});
console.log(x);
```

I also want to add another key-value pair to `data` then `arr` element is `xyz`.

I want to add `['id']: k` but only when `arr` elem is `xyz` and then push it to `x`.

Comment: Have you tried an `if` or a ternary?

Comment: I did, but I dont know how to add the `k`. I tried to add it to the forEach

Comment: I see what you mean. You could modify the `data` function to add the property conditionally or you can have `data` take an optional function that conditionally adds the property

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Something like `const data = (sd, extraProperties) =>... Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({...extraProperties(k, g), name: k}) 
           ` then you can write `[...x, ...(y === 'xyz' ? data(y, (k, g) => ({id: k})) : data(y, ()= ({})))]` then in data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example how you can have a conditional key value in your data.

```js
// Try edit message
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const data2 = data.map(item => {
  let predefined = {
    value: item,
  };
  if (item === 2) predefined.id = item;
  return predefined;
})
console.log(data2)
```